# When an adjective clause modifies two or more nouns that are connected by "or", do I use a plural or singular verb?

Tags: grammar

When an adjective clause modifies two or more nouns that are connected by "or", do I use a plural or singular verb?

**Example 1:**

> You need to buy a powerful computer or tablet that **supports/support** this kind of application.

**Example 2:**

> I think you need a new car, bike, or bicycle which **is/are** affordable while you stay here.

Comment: You are recommending one thing _or_ another, not both - so the verb in the adjective clause should be singular.

Comment: Example 1 - supports; Example 2 - is

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kate Bunting's comment - in the examples you have provided the thing being described by the adjective clause is singular, thus the verb is singular.

It's important to note that if you were listing plural nouns instead, the verb would be plural.  For example:

*You need to buy powerful **computers or tablets** that **support** this kind of application.*

*I think you need new **cars, bikes, or bicycles** which **are** affordable while you stay here.*